# How Do I Add a Fade out affect to my JavaScript slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I currently am working on simple web page and have added a slideshow of three images using JavaScript. I like the way how one other websites the slideshows fade in and out of each image instead of just changing abruptly. Please tell me how to add this affect to my current code while only using CSS, standard HTML and Java Script.  Here is my HTML code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
            <title>Car Of Your Dreams Australia</title>
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="?\favicon.ico">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
            <h1> Car Of Your Dreams Australia </h1>


<script type="text/javascript">

var slideimages = new Array() 
slideimages[0] = new Image() 
slideimages[0].src = "r8.jpg" 
slideimages[1] = new Image()
slideimages[1].src = "California.jpg"
slideimages[2] = new Image()
slideimages[2].src = "SLSAMG.jpg"

</script>
<body>
        <img src="r8.jpg" id= "slide" width=1336 height=768 />

        <script type = "text/javascript">
        var step=0

        function slideit(){
        if (!document.images)
        return
        document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step].src
        if (step<2)
        step++
        else
        step=0
        setTimeout("slideit()",5000)
        }

        slideit()

        </script>
</body>

        </head>
        </html>
```

and my CSS

```
body {background-color:#000000;}
h1 {color:#FF0040;}
p1 {color:#C1CDCD;}

h1 {
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 11px;
}

p1 {
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 14px;
}

h1.italic {font-style:italic;}

.boxed {
    margin-right:750px;
    position:absolute;
    left:60px;
    top:100px;
    z-index:+1;
    border: 5px outset #E0EEEE;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Unless your requireements require that you avoid javascript frameworks I would look into RevealJS.

http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/

Reveal has the specific actions your looking at (fade in and fade out) and much more documented. They also have a hosted platform if thats something your looking for as well as the open source version for you to download and play with. I personally use it for all my custom developed HTML driven slide decks.

Answer (score 0):

Give the image a baseline opacity, and identify that all transitions towards opacity of this element are to occur over the period of 1 second.

```
img{
    opacity:1;
    transition:opacity 1s;
}
```

Create a new class that has an opacity of 0.

```
img.fade{
    opacity:0;
}
```

Add this class to the element when slideit(); spawns:

```
function slideit(){
    document.getElementById('slide').classList.add('fade');
```

Add a timeout function directly after that occurs after 1 second, which will change the SRC of the element and will also remove the fade class, thus firing the transition again.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step].src;
    document.getElementById('slide').classList.remove('fade');
}, 1000);
```

Now when the function executes, the existing image will fade out over 1 second, then the image's SRC will change, and then will fade in over 1 second.

Comment: Its still not working, as all that happens is it fades into the first image then stays there. Could you please post a copy of the complete code for me?